# CSS affecting siblings img

Tags: html, css

I have run in to this irritating problem that I can't seem to get around: the HTML code looks like this

```
<form>
<lable><img src="/image.png"/></lable>
<input type="text" name="name" required/>
</form>
```

I seek to apply a filter to the lable's `img` when there is focus on the `input`. I have tried both with:

```
input:focus ~ lable>img{filter...}
input:focus + lable>img{filter...}
input:focus lable>img{filter...}
input:focus img{filter...}
```

But nothing seems to have an effect. Is it my localhost doing tricks or do I have to try something totally different? and if then what? Looking forward to hear from you wizards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectors **+** and **~** both working for the next element(s), So you must to bring the `input` before the `label`. If you want your label is in the left of the input put them in a right to left div or set float left for label:

```
<form>
  <div style="direction: rtl;">        
    <input type="text" name="name" required/>
    <lable><img src="/image.png"/></lable>
 </div>
</form>
```

Or

```
<form>      
  <input type="text" name="name" required/>
  <lable style="float:left;"><img src="/image.png"/></lable>
</form>
```

Comment: genius :* thanks alot !

Comment: You welcome my friend...